# Django: migrating one manytomany field to another manytomany field

Tags: django, django-migrations

I need to migrate some data from class `A` to class `B`

class A contains a m2m field that, say, links to `auth.User`

This is simply migrating data over, so I add those fields from class A into class B and created migration file. I then loop through all class A objects and assign those fields for each object into class B.

When it gets to the m2m field, I run into `TypeError: 'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable`

```
class A(object):
    something = CharField(blehbleh)
    something_else = CharField(blehbleh)
    thing_to_migrate = models.ManyToManyField('auth.User', related_name='some_name', blank=True)
    class_b = models.ForeignKey('class_B_path', related_name='some_name', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)  # so A.class_b gets me class B

class B(object):
    already_exist_field = CharField(blehbleh)
    thing_I_want_to_migrate_here = models.ManyToManyField('auth.User', related_name='some_other_name', blank=True)
```

`related_name` needs to be unique, so I set a new name there. When I modify the migration script

first the def

```
def migrate_lpinvite_to_invite(apps, schema_editor):
    ClassA = apps.get_model('appname', 'A')
    for obj in ClassA.objects.all():
        obj.class_B.thing_I_want_to_migrate_here = obj.thing_to_migrate
        obj.save()
```

then actual runmigration

```
operations = [
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='B',
        name='thing_I_want_to_migrate_here',
        field=models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, related_name='some_other_name', to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),

    migrations.RunPython(migrate_to_B)
]
```

And I got the error listed above. What's the correct way to migrate related fields like this? Can I somehow refer to the through table directly and don't do this kind of data migration?

Comment: Are you sure that is the error you get? The code you have posted would give "Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited." Please show the full traceback.

Comment: I figured out. I need to do `obj.class_B.thing_I_want_to_migrate_here.add(*obj.thing_to_migrate.all())` instead. I didn't get the direct assignment error, but I think this actually solves that problem too.